# How to write a code recursively and pass the value dynamically in java as shown below picture?

Tags: java, recursion

```
public static void getSome(int x) {
    int i, j, k, l, m, temp = (x - (x - 1));
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++) {
        System.out.print("X");
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (l = 1; l >= (x / 2); l--) {
        for (j = 1; j <= l; j++) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
    }
    for (m = (x - (x + 1)); m >= 1; m--) {
        for (k = temp; k <= m; k--) {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
        System.out.print("X");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

The above code having issue, even its not recursive function, Could you please any one help me out.

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "pass the value dynamically"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this output

```
X     X
 X   X
  X X
   X
  X X
 X   X
X     X
```

With this function to print one row

```
private static void printRow(int width, int level) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (width < 1) return;

    for (int i = 0; i < level; i++) {
        sb.append(" ");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        if (i == 0 || i == width - 1) {
            sb.append("X");
        }
        else {
            sb.append(" ");
        }
    }
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

This is the hard-coded iterative approach

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printRow(7, 0);
    printRow(5, 1);
    printRow(3, 2);
    printRow(1, 3);
    printRow(3, 2);
    printRow(5, 1);
    printRow(7, 0);
}
```

This is the recursive approach

```
private static void printX(int width, int level) {
    if (width < 2) {
        if (width == 1) {
            printRow(width, level);
        }
        return;
    }
    printRow(width, level);
    printX(width - 2, level+1);
    printRow(width, level);
}

private static void printX(int width) {
    printX(width, 0);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    printX(7);
}
```